# Why I get different array after encoding?

Tags: php, arrays, encoding

I want to encode array to string for this I use two functions:

```
function HashArray($data = array()){
    $key = md5('hash');
    $cipher = "rijndael-256";
    $mode = "cbc";
    $data = serialize($data);
    return m_encrypt($data, $key, $cipher, $mode);
}

function UnHashArray($data = array()){
    $key = md5('hash');
    $cipher = "rijndael-256";
    $mode = "cbc";
    return m_decrypt($data, $key, $cipher, $mode);
}
```

Call function to hash:

```
<? $string = HashArray(array('id' => $article->idArticle, 'typeLike' => '1', 'content' => 2, 'contentTypeSub' => 0));?>
```

After $string is sent to server by AJAX, so on server PHP I get hashed string:

```
$array = UnHashArray($this->input->post('data'));
var_dump($array); die();
```

It gives me string:

```
string(96) "a:4:{s:2:"id";N;s:8:"typeLike";s:1:"1";s:7:"content";i:2;s:14:"contentTypeSub";i:0;}"
```

What I do wrong?

Comment: Why do you think you're doing something wrong? Just compare **5** lines of encoding function with **4 !!!** lines of decoding one.

Comment: Have you actually bothered *reading* the code yet?

Comment: You are serializing your data, but you are not reversing that serialization … if you want your array data structure again, then use `unserialize` on the decrypted string you now got.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I will `unserialize`. But there is a easy way do it in Codeigniter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your `HashArray` Method you have

```
$data = serialize($data);
```

Your missing something like this in your `UnHashArray` Method

```
$data = unserialize($data);
```